# Disable Javascript click events in C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, dom-events

**Intro:**
I'm working on a C# WinForms + WebBrowser project.
I'd like to do some processing upon a click on a hyperlink.

Here's how I hook a click event to every hyperlink in an HTML document:

```
void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted( object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser.Document.Links;
    foreach ( HtmlElement link in links )
    {
      link.Click += delegate { MessageBox.Show( "C# Click!" ); };
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**
The above code works well, but the problem is that I get side effects from javascript code which also performs some clicking action.

I learned the hard way that this problem comes in many shapes and forms..
Here's a *not so obvious* example of a jQuery action that makes life harder:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    alert("jQuery Click!");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Click Me!</a>
</body>

</html>
<html>

<body>
```

What happens here is that when clicking a hyperlink in the `WebBrowser` control - the "jQuery Click!" alert will pop up first, and only after dismissing it will the "C# Click!" message be shown.

**The Question:**
I've searched far and wide, but didn't yet come up with an answer.

How could I C#-programmatically prevent jQuery or any other form of javascript code from being executed in the WebBrowser?

**Clarification:**
I'd like to say I already tried to alter the document in many ways, e.g. stripping `<script>` tags from `webBrowser.DocumentText`, and from the inner html node, and by working with `HtmlElement` and the underlying `IHtmlElement` objects...

But no luck..

Changing the `webBrowser.DocumentText` causes the document to get reloaded from a string, and thus I lose any credentials (e.g. cookie) I had to the original site. And changing `IHtmlElement` objects doesn't really make a difference 'cause the jQuery script was already loaded so, again, I am unable to prevent the event from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to disable JavaScript execution in WebBrowser component.
The only you can do is to suppress the error messages with `ScriptErrorsSupressed` property set to false.
An idea would be to pre-filter your HTML and eliminate all your "onclick" events from HTML using regular expressions before you render your HTML in the WebBrowser component.

Comment: As I mentioned in the Clarification section, I already tried that. The things is that I wanna follow links and download referred files. This requires having an authenticated session.
Bt stripping tags and reloading from a string or even from a local files, I lose the authenticated session (which misses the whole point).